# How do you evalutate$ \int_0^\pi sin(m\theta) \frac{\partial^n }{\partial \theta^n} ((cos\theta) ^2-1)^n d\theta$ with m>n and m+n =odd integer

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials, legendre-symbol

In proving the orthogonality of the Legendre polynomials, I have encountered this problem

$$ \int_0^\pi \sin(m\theta) \frac{\partial^n }{\partial \theta^n} [(\cos^{2}\theta -1)^n] d\theta$$

with $m > n$ and $m+n$ an odd integer.

I know that

[image]

but then I don't know how to move on, can anyone help me with that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $x{}{}$?

Comment: ah, i am a rookie here, thanks for your comment ~

Answer (score 1):

Integrating by parts we get
$$
A=\int_0^\pi \sin(m\theta) \frac{d^n }{d \theta^n} [(\cos^{2}\theta -1)^n] d\theta\\
=\sin(m\theta) \frac{d^{n-1} }{d \theta^{n-1}} [(\cos^{2}\theta -1)^n] {\Large{|}}_{0}^{\pi}-m\int_0^\pi \cos(m\theta) \frac{d^{n-1} }{d \theta^{n-1}} [(\cos^{2}\theta -1)^n] d\theta.
$$
The quantity
$$
\frac{d^{n-k} }{d \theta^{n-k}} [(\cos^{2}\theta -1)^n] {\Large{|}}_{0}^{\pi}=0,\qquad k\in\mathbb{N}
$$
since the derivatives
$$
\frac{d^{n-k} }{d \theta^{n-k}} [(\cos^{2}\theta -1)^n] ,\qquad k\in\mathbb{N}
$$
are proportional to $1-\cos^2\theta$.

Finally we get
$$
A=\int_0^\pi \sin^{2n}\theta\frac{d^n }{d \theta^n}\sin(m\theta)  d\theta.
$$
Now depending whether $n$ and $m$ are odd or even you can calculate this by applying binomial theorem to obtain the integral as a finite sum.

Comment: oh, the key step is at second step,thank you for suggestion~